# Getting data from a single table into multiple json arrays

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get data from a single table using multiple queries. Suppose I have the following table:

MY TABLE:

[image]

I'm trying to **get `PARA_NUMBER` 1 and `PARA_NUMBER` 2 and combining** them using this query:

```
(SELECT * FROM `t_sen` WHERE `PARA_NUMBER` = 1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `t_sen` WHERE `PARA_NUMBER` = 2)
```

And then I get the results in JSON format which looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "PARA_NUMBER": "1",
        "TEXT": "Hello"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "PARA_NUMBER": "1",
        "TEXT": "how"
    },
    // rest of the rows

    {
        "ID": "6",
        "PARA_NUMBER": "2",
        "TEXT": "Hope"
    },
    {
        "ID": "7",
        "PARA_NUMBER": "2",
        "TEXT": "you're"
    },
    // rest of the rows
]
```

However, I want something like this:

```
[
    "1": {
            "ID": "1",
            "PARA_NUMBER": "1",
            "TEXT": "Hello"
         },
         {
            "ID": "2",
            "PARA_NUMBER": "1",
            "TEXT": "how"
         },
         // rest of the rows

    "2": {
            "ID": "6",
            "PARA_NUMBER": "2",
            "TEXT": "Hope"
         },
         {
            "ID": "7",
            "PARA_NUMBER": "2",
            "TEXT": "you're"
         },
         // rest of the rows
]
```

Where every `PARA_NUMBER` have their own branches. I'm using very simple PHP code to output the JSON data:

```
$myquery = "
        (SELECT * FROM t_sen WHERE PARA_NUMBER = 1)
        UNION
        (SELECT * FROM t_sen WHERE PARA_NUMBER = 2)
    ";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $myquery);

    if (!$query) {
        echo mysqli_error($conn);  //You need to put $conn here to display error.
        die();
    }

    $data = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: You will need to post process in your application framework. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP and MySQL. It's just simple getting the results from the table and printing it out in a JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `mysqli` interface in PHP, you could do something like this (assuming your connection is called `$conn`):

```
$result = $conn->query('(SELECT * FROM `t_sen` WHERE `PARA_NUMBER` = 1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `t_sen` WHERE `PARA_NUMBER` = 2)');
$out = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $out[$row['PARA_NUMBER']][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($out);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfectly! :) I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer of Nick already works, I don't see the need to use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html). Why don't you use [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) instead?

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM `t_sen` WHERE `PARA_NUMBER` IN (1,2)');
$out = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $out[$row['PARA_NUMBER']][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($out);
```

Comment: Wow I didn't knew I can do that. Thanks a lot for this! I really appreciate this :)